# WAS IT WRONG TO ASK: Minimum time for responding to someones answer?

Tags: discussion

This was the content ([link to deleted question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/how-much-minimum-time-is-suitable-react-to-answer-in-se)):

> I have been through this question a lot of time as if i wait keep staring too long it keeps eating my time if i also sit relaxed and not curious and impatient (as we all can do it perfectly) about it then it may be that the answer-er may get bored or something (sometimes i take almost a day or two due heavy schedule) so at both ends if people are impatient then i don't think its effective technique to just be patient or use smartphone app (which i don't) to distract self and still have the answers.
>
> Don't judge me but might get a bit late on this one too.

This question got 2 down votes so the author deleted, so was it irrelevant to ask here?

Comment: What question are you talking about?

Comment: Even now it is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're talking about [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/how-much-minimum-time-is-suitable-react-to-answer-in-se), which you deleted shortly after you asked it (I'm not sure why you're referring to yourself in the third person ("so the author deleted").

The content of the question is what you've posted in your question here, which is why I was initially confused. Please, be sure to explain your meta questions thoroughly. Because the question is deleted and you don't link to it, only a moderator could find it. The question was:

> **How much minimum time is suitable react to answer in SE?**
>
> I have been through this question a lot of time as if i wait keep staring too long it keeps eating my time if i also sit relaxed and not curious and impatient (as we all can do it perfectly) about it then it may be that the answer-er may get bored or something (sometimes i take almost a day or two due heavy schedule) so at both ends if people are impatient then i don't think its effective technique to just be patient or use smartphone app (which i don't) to distract self and still have the answers.
>
> Don't judge me but might get a bit late on this one too
> Any thoughts?

I'm not sure it's clear what you're asking here.

In the time it was posted, it received two downvotes and two close votes - one for "off topic, not about interpersonal skills" and one as "off topic, belongs on Meta".

If given the chance, I'd probably have closed it as "unclear what you're asking".

Based on the question, I'm guessing you're not a native English speaker - which is completely fine! But we need to be able to understand what you're asking and, I'm afraid, it's completely unclear to me. Besides that, we do limit the scope of questions we accept here *about* Stack Exchange. It's discussed in [this meta question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1243/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-about-issues-on-stack-exchange-if-so-where-do-we-dra). If you have a general question about Stack Exchange, we recommend you ask it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

When you do ask, please be sure to make things as clear as you can - use examples, keep your explanation concise. You talk about what the minimum time is for reacting to answers in your title but your body talks about taking a long time to respond. These are opposite things, making the question, again, unclear.

Comment: "I'm guessing you're not a native English speaker" --what was the fault in it?? @Catija

Comment: There are many general errors... not capitalizing "I", "a lot of time" should be "a lot of times"... but it is mostly unclear what you're saying, so it doesn't seem like something a native speaker would write. "Don't judge me but might get a bit late on this one too"... doesn't make sense.

Comment: Be careful not to try and micro manage the stack.   The content of the questions and answers are **far** more important than any grammar issues.

Comment: @IamSoNotListening What do you mean? The question is completely unclear regardless of grammar and typos.

Comment: @IamSoNotListening - Sure... as long as the post is understandable despite those errors. If it's so unreadable that we can't tell what it's talking about... that *is* an issue.

Comment: @ArwenUndómiel I am speaking in general terms, not just this particular question.

Comment: @Catija I am speaking in general terms, not just this particular question.

Comment: @IamSoNotListening This question isn't general and neither is the answer. As far as I'm aware we've not closed or downvoted questions merely for grammar issues. Also, writing your comment twice was unnecessary.

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that we have no shortage of users who fix grammar, correct spelling or improve formatting, as long as we understand, what the respective user wants to express. That's how we deal with these issues (*in general*) here, not by downvoting and closing.

Comment: @Catija good to know....

Comment: @AnneDaunted I'm not aware of any site on the stack that closes questions specifically for grammar issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I understood your question:

> **What is the ideal response time to an answer on Stack Exchange websites?**
>
> After asking a question on SE, I can either keep checking back for answers impatiently within a short time period, but it wastes my time if there are no answers; or else I can be relaxed and check back only at longer intervals like maybe once a day or once in 2 days, but the person who wrote the answer might get bored by the delayed response. Between these 2 options, what is the ideal response time to an answer on Stack Exchange websites?

If that is the question you wanted to ask, then it might be more suitable to ask it here on Interpersonal Skills meta than our main site, and most ideal to ask it on https://meta.stackexchange.com which is the meta site for the whole network, as already pointed out in the detailed earlier answer by @Catija.

However, you need not delete a question just for getting 2 downvotes and 2 close votes (although you cannot see the close votes.) Interpersonal.SE is one of the most friendly and welcoming communities on the Stack Exchange network and we will ***work with you*** to help you edit to make your question clearly understood, and try to get it answered on the appropriate website within the network.

Comment: So, I'm curious... do you think the question as you've written it is actually a valid question on SE? It seems like purely opinion and situation based to me.

Comment: You are probably right @Catija. ***If*** that is what OP intended (and I am awaiting confirmation on that point), our response would be to help OP modify the question to be a good fit for SE. OP seems a very new member everywhere on the SE network.